# javascript setTimeout fuction,is something wrong with it

Tags: javascript, html, loops, settimeout

i use settimeout function, why it is not working. i just want to change the image after every 2 seconds. but nothing is happenting it is showing only first image but it is not changing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function parta(){
            document.getElementById("carimg").src="c1.img";
            window.setTimeout(partb,2000);
        }
        function partb(){
            document.getElementById("carimg").src="c2.jpg";
            window.setTimeout(partc,2000);
        }
        function partc(){
            document.getElementById("carimg").src="c3.jpg";
            window.setTimeout(parta,2000);
        }


</script>
```

Comment: What is the reason for your `while`?

Comment: You're defining 3 functions, but never calling them. It also probably should not be in a while loop

Comment: even if i remove this while loop its not working, i appllied it for infinite loop

Comment: thank you all, I got my answer, JLRishe thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring three functions over and over and never calling any of them.

If you want to toggle between three images, put them in an array and go through the array one element at a time using `setInterval`:

```
var images = ['c1.img', 'c2.jpg', 'c3.jpg'];
var imgNum = 0;

function rotateImage() {
    document.getElementById("carimg").src= images[imgNum];
    imgNum = (imgNum + 1) % images.length;
}

rotateImage();
setInterval(rotateImage, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your code close to what you have right now, you only need to change a few things:

```js
function parta() {
  document.getElementById("carimg").src="c1.img";
  window.setTimeout(partb,2000);
}
function partb() {
  document.getElementById("carimg").src="c2.jpg";
  window.setTimeout(partc,2000);
}
function partc() {
  document.getElementById("carimg").src="c3.jpg";
  window.setTimeout(parta,2000);
}

parta();
```

Using `while` is not necessary in this case, since each function will call each other after 2 seconds. However, you still need to get that "loop" started, which is why you need to call `parta()`. Also, it might make more sense to use `setInterval` in this case.

You can play with this code snippet on CodePen: https://codepen.io/yvesgurcan/pen/RwwOawO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
let imageSrc = ['c1.img', 'c2.jpg', 'c3.jpg'];
let imgIndex;
setInterval(()=>{
    if(imgIndex == undefined) {
        imgIndex = 0;
    } else {
        if(imgIndex >= imageSrc.length - 1) {
            imgIndex = 0;
        } else {
            imgIndex++;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("carimg").src = imageSrc[imgIndex];
}, 2000);
```